# Daily digest of specific Subreddit?

Tags: reddit

Is it possible to receive a daily digest of the best/hottest posts on a specific Subreddit? Does Reddit offer that natively or is there a third-party service that does that?

Answer (score 0):

I use [If This Then That](https://ifttt.com) to do this. [Here](https://ifttt.com/applets/biJKbfTg-reddit-weekly-digest?term=reddit%20digest) is an example.

The example is weekly, but IFTTT can be configured and set daily.